# Using "isEqualToString" to set label text

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to use a string on parse.com to set the text inside a UILabel. On Parse I have a string column called "isItemOnSpecial" and if the item is on special i will set it to yes. if the string is set to yes then i would like the UILabel to display the string from the column specialPrice othwerwise i would like the UILabel to be hidden. Here is my code:

```
// This is where I am setting up my tableViewCell//

NSString *itemOnSpecial = [object objectForKey:@"isItemOnSpecial"];

if ([itemOnSpecial isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
    UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    specialLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"specialPrice"];
} else {
    UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    [specialLabel setHidden:true];
}
```

When i run the app using this code the UILabel is always set hidden.
Any help with this would be much appreciated it's been bugging me for a long time.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What's the output of `[object objectForKey:@"isItemOnSpecial"]`?

Comment: yah..check `NSLog(@"%@",[object objectForKey:@"isItemOnSpecial"]);`

Comment: `if( [@"Some String" caseInsensitiveCompare:@"yes"] == NSOrderedSame )` try this

Comment: I believe the label is always set to hidden, because the text is always equals to "yes" :) Output the string 'itemOnSpecial' to see what it really is, I think you should solve this error where you set the objectForKey:@"isItemOnSpecial"

Comment: Okay so I added NSLog(@"%@",[object objectForKey:@"isItemOnSpecial"]); to my code and the output that I received was: 
2013-08-26 21:50:40.134 sengSokk[2145:12b03] error: (null)
2013-08-26 21:50:40.137 sengSokk[2145:12b03] (null)
2013-08-26 21:50:40.140 sengSokk[2145:12b03] (null)
2013-08-26 21:50:40.141 sengSokk[2145:12b03] (null)
2013-08-26 21:50:40.143 sengSokk[2145:12b03] (null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most immediate problem I see is that it looks like you're using this code for a UITableViewCell, or similar in which case you need to be sure to unhide the label that may have been hidden by a previous load of the cell. For example:

```
NSString *itemOnSpecial = [object objectForKey:@"isItemOnSpecial"];

if ([itemOnSpecial caseInsensitiveCompare:@"yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {
    UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    specialLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"specialPrice"];
    [specialLabel setHidden:NO]; // Notice this line
}else{
    UILabel *specialLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:5];
    [specialLabel setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: hmm...I think problem will be the case sensitive character.

Comment: Hi there, I tried doing it this way but specialLabel.text now shows @"specialPrice" even if "isItemOnSpecial" is set to "no".

Comment: I had a capital letter where i shouldn't have. Stupid mistake! Your code works perfectly. Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
if( [@"Some String" caseInsensitiveCompare:@"some string"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
  // strings are equal except for possibly case
}
```

OR this:

```
[someString compare:otherString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: Thanks Armaan but i can't seem to get it working using these methods